# What deos X window id 0 means - No window created?

Tags: c, graphics, render, x11

When I print value of a window handle  (X11 simple window ), it gives zero. Does there exist a window?

What I have is the below logs at the two positions in a C program. I need to make sure the two windows are same. *I printed there ids, it comes out to be 0. I doubt if this is the same window or no window has been created at all* ?

> printf("\n Window id is ... %d",win);

The result is 0.

Question - If the value printed for an X window is 0. Does that means there is no window. Or is it a proper id ?

Edited after answers  ---
1.To print Window as int is fine and have done that before. Values like 223021 gets printed in both the printfs. using format specifier %u also yield the same result.

2.Win is declared as Window win;

Comment: Please, how is `win` declared?

Comment: win declared as Window win;

Comment: No, printing Window as `int` is NOT fine. It may work by coincidence on your system, but generally it does not. Turn on `-Wall` to see get a warning in gcc. You must cast to the type which you specify in the format string.

Comment: However printing as `long` (`"%ld"`) should be portable.

Comment: Yes did that too.  printf("\n Window id is ... %lu",(unsigned long) win). Same result. But this is not the question.

Comment: You need to show us some actual code so the problem can be seen.

Answer (score 0):

On my system, `sizeof(Window)` yields 8, while `sizeof(int)` yields 4. That's probably why your printf prints 0: `printf("%d", someWindow)` uses the first 4 of 8 bytes, while only the last ones may be significant.

You must cast the Window to a well-known type instead

```
printf("%d", (int) win);
printf("%ld", (long) win);
```

The bigger the type you use, the better, probably. In fact, I'm not even sure if a `Window` must be implemented as an arithmetic type.